# Как сделать аудит? discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Я делаю своего дискорд бота и очень долго не понимаю как сделать аудит как у juniper бота помогите пожалуйста :D

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: используйте базу данных

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите Логировать действия пользователей по типу этого - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То вам необходимо использовать обработчики event(), такие как `on_message_edit`, `on_message_delete` и т.п.

Подробно про каждый из них вы сможете прочитать здесь - [discord.py Api Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message_delete#event-reference)

Пример кода для логирования удалённых сообщений -

````py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
            channel = bot.get_channel(ID_КАНАЛА)
            embed = discord.Embed(color=16744576) # Создаём embed с цветом 16744576

            #Добавляем ему Fied`сы с данными
            embed.add_field(name="ID канала", value=f"{message.id}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Автор Сообщения:", value=f"<@{message.author.id}>", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Канал:", value=f"<#{message.channel.id}>", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Содержимое сообщения:", value=f"```\n{message.content}\n```", inline=False) # Здесь мы получаем само удалённое сообщение

            await channel.send(embed=embed) # Отправляем лог в channel
````